# How to separate different properties of a css gradient?

Tags: css, gradient

If I have css gradient code that looks like this:

```
 background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at center, #E6E6E6 0%, #BABABA 100%);
```

I'd like to separate the different properties of the gradient to make it more flexible. I mean I should be able to define the different properties (ie circle, farthest-side at center, etc.) as a different property each on separate lines.

Would that be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not currently possible, as CSS3 only offers a single functional notation that takes all the values as parameters, rather than a set of properties, for expressing a certain kind of gradient.

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#gradients) implies that this is to make it easier for a browser to generate a gradient on the fly:

> The gradient notations described in this section allow an author to specify such an image in a terse syntax, so that the UA can generate the image automatically when rendering the page.

I imagine splitting it into properties would either make style resolution or the syntax too complex, which is why they opted for a functional notation instead.

Comment: +1 - This may help too - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/radial-gradient

Comment: Would I be able to create something like a variable in css so I can substitute it. The reason I want to do that is because I have several statements for each of the different browser rendering toolkits (ie, webkit, moz, o, etc. ). I'd look to be able to change the 'from' and 'to' color values just once to change the color scheme without having to go through every single statement. Thanks.

Comment: @hesson: The most common solution is to make use of a preprocessor such as Sass or LESS, or use a script that automatically inserts prefixed properties for you such as [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.com) (which has been updated to handle recent changes in vendor-specific gradient syntax).

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible currently. The only option available to you is something like;

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.27, rgb(100,173,97)),
    color-stop(0.64, rgb(130,208,127)),
    color-stop(0.82, rgb(156,250,166))
);
```